# Isomorphism with operation $a^{log b}$

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

On a homework assignment on a course on group theory we tot asked

> Prove that $G_{, \cdot} \cong \mathbb{R}^{+}$ where $G=\mathbb{R}_{>1}$ with the operation $a \cdot b=a^{\log b}$

So I figured the challenge was finding a bijection $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}_{>1}$ with the constraint $f(a+b)=f(a)^{\log f(b)}$. I tried $f(x)=e^{x}+1$ bit that didn't work out. Am I overlooking something trivial, or should I focus on proving the existence of the isomorphism instead of finding a function?

Comment: This is probably easier if you directly look for an isomorphism with $\mathbb{R}^+$ as the problem suggests, rather than with $\mathbb{R}$ as you are doing.

Comment: Hint: $a^x=e^{x\log a}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try to rewrite the operation $a\cdot b$ in a more symmetric form, where $a$ and $b$ have similar roles. Does this form suggest an $f$ to you?

Comment: So in the form $e^{\log a \log b}$, I still don't see a possible $f$ now. I'm pretty sure it has something to do with a exponential function.

Comment: @stijndelnoij You want a bijection $f:G\to\mathbb R^+$ such that $f(a\cdot b)=f(a)f(b)$. Equivalently, $a\cdot b=f^{-1}\left(f(a)f(b)\right)$. Can you compare that with your expression for $a\cdot b$?

Comment: Got it figured out finally, I was thinking the whole time that $\mathbb{R}^{+}$ was the set $\mathbb{R}$ with operation $+$. Now I see that it is just $f(x)=\log x$